# AJAX call using JQuery not setting variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I'm trying to validate a CAPTCHA using reCAPTCHA and AJAX.

I have a function to do it all but I need to return a true or false value to the calling function to specify whether to submit the form or not.

My AJAX call is being processed correctly but where I set the flag to show that the CAPTCHA was not valid is not being set.

I'm not explaining that well so here's the code:

```
function validateComment(isReply)
{ 
    formValid = true;
    if (isReply) { qualifier = "Reply"; } else { qualifier = "New"; }
    $("#comment" + qualifier + "Error").hide();
    $.post("/scripts/checkcaptcha.php", 
    { 
        recaptcha_challenge_field : $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(), 
        recaptcha_response_field : $('#recaptcha_response_field').val() 
    },
        function(data) 
        {
            if (data == "invalid")
            {
                $("#comment" + qualifier + "Error").html("<p>Incorrect CAPTCHA entered</p>");
                $("#comment" + qualifier + "Error").slideDown();
                formValid = false;
                Recaptcha.reload();
            } 
        }
    );
    alert(formValid);
    return false;
}
```

Where I set `formValid = false` is not working for some reason, it's not being set so with the code above `formValid` is always true which is incorrect.

I'm guessing this has something to do with how things are being processed.

Any ideas as to why and how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `formValid` variable declaration outside of your function? Thinking this could be a scoping problem...

Comment: Did you check (with a debug point, or alert) whether the statement `formValid = false` is executed? How about the statements before that in `if(data == "invalid")`?

Comment: Everything is getting executed except for `formValid = false;`.  I tried moving `formValid = true;` outside the function and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: @Tom, did you try with a debug point/breakpoint? Do you see the statement getting executed or getting "skipped" by the browser? If it is getting executed, does the value change (See the "Locals" or "Scope Variables" section in the debugger/console) to false, but somehow magically changes back to true? or does the value never change at all?

Comment: The .html, .slideDown and .reload() statements all get executed.  It's the setting of the variable that seems to be getting skipped.  Or maybe it is being processed and it's some asynchronous issue with AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because the validateComment function is executed first. Your ajax response handling function is a callback function, so it is not executed until after the response is loaded (validateComment has already been executed and returned a value by this point). How you can fix this is by setting a global boolean variable (e.g is_loaded) and then go into a loop and keep wait until a is_loaded is true, or you can use setInvterval to check every 100ms or something.

Edit: Or you can try loading the response into a variable and checking for errors that way.

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  async: false
}).responseText;
```

Comment: Any reason why this is returning a blank? `var test = $.ajax({url : "/scripts/checkcaptcha.php", type : "POST", data : ({recaptcha_challenge_field : $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(), recaptcha_response_field : $('#recaptcha_response_field').val() }),datatype : "html",async : false}).responseText;` The php page just outputs valid and invalid `echo 'invalid'`, etc

Comment: Great! Sorry wasn't home so couldn't helped you out sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
function validateComment(isReply,callback)
{ 
    var callback=callback||false,formValid = true,qualifier = "New";
    if (isReply) qualifier = "Reply";
    $("#comment" + qualifier + "Error").hide();
    $.post("/scripts/checkcaptcha.php", 
    { 
        recaptcha_challenge_field : $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(), 
        recaptcha_response_field : $('#recaptcha_response_field').val() 
    },
    function(data){
            if (data == "invalid")
            {
                $("#comment" + qualifier + "Error").html("<p>Incorrect CAPTCHA entered</p>");
                $("#comment" + qualifier + "Error").slideDown();
                formValid = false;
                Recaptcha.reload();
            }
   }).complete(function(){
        if(typeof callback=='function') callback(formValid);
   });
}

validateComment(true,function(formValid){
    if(formValid){
    //...
    }
    else{
    //...
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work `<input type="image" class="image" src="/_assets/img/buttons/submit.gif" alt="Submit" onclick="return validateComment(true,function(formValid){if(formValid){alert('valid');}else{alert('invalid');}});" />` ... any idea as to why?

Comment: try the new one and tell me what it is displayed.

Comment: Hey Darm, I actually got the `$.ajax` stuff above to work beautifully.  I +1'd you as much as I could in appreciation though, thanks.

Comment: you can remove the .error(function(){
        alert('ajax failed');
   }) part, I added it to check if you had an ajax error.